# Default dates for laravel datepicker

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, datepicker

I have 2 successfully working Vue Datepicker instances and I'm trying to use them to filter an axios call that is being made on each change. I'm using Vue in laravel and I want the datepicker instances to both default to the current date so that any datepicker change making the axios call will at least have a date in each instance.

This is working to send the selected date value for the filter, but I"m unsure how to properly set each date value to the current date.

What's the best way to resolve this so that every call to this method will have a start or end date?

```
 <datepicker :value="startDate" @selected="callDate"></datepicker>

 <datepicker :value="endDate" @selected="callDate"></datepicker>


data() {
  return {
    startDate: '',
    endDate: ''
  }
}

...

methods: { 
  fetchData(, startDate = '', endDate = '') {
        axios.get('/report/assets/data', {params:{startDate: startDate, endDate: endDate}})
        .then(response => {
          // handle success
          console.log(response.data)
          this.rows = response.data
        })
    },
}

callDate(date){
        if(date) {
            const dateString = date.toISOString().substring(0,10);
            console.log(dateString);
        } else {
            console.log('null date');
        }

        this.fetchAssetReport(dateString);
    }
```